# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 308, Size: 308

Tags: java

```
    HtmlPage page = null;
    List <HtmlElement> ips = null ;
    List <HtmlElement> ports = null ; 

    ArrayList <String> proxies = new ArrayList();
    String temp;
    String baseUrl = "https://free-proxy-list.net/" ;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

    try{
        page = client.getPage(baseUrl);

        ips = page.getByXPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[position()=1]/text()");
        ports = page.getByXPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[position()=2]/text()");

        for(int i=0;i<ips.size();i++){
            System.out.println("IP: "+ips.get(i));

            temp=(ips.get(i)+":"+ports.get(i));
            System.out.println("Temp: "+temp);
            if(!(temp.matches(".*[a-z].*"))){
                proxies.add(temp);
            }
       }
        for (int i=0;i<ips.size();i++){
            System.out.println(proxies.get(i));
         }

   }

    catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

hello, i keep getting error like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 308, Size: 308` on this passage: `temp=(ips.get(i)+":"+ports.get(i));`
Can't understand why

Comment: Max index is 307 with size of 308.

Comment: The `ports` list must have one less item in it than the `ips` list.

Comment: You want to iterate `ips.size() -1`.

Comment: Print `ips.size()` and `ports.size()` second one may be not of same size

Comment: @azro You're right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Every good development environment includes an integrated debugger. You must learn to use one of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe ips.size() != ports.size()

Comment: ye, ips is 309 and ports is 308, how can i fix it?

Comment: scan the table, and figure out - which column (td) is missing. 
option1: For any given IP, if there is no port specified, you may assign default port.
option2: add additional condition -
              for(int i=0;i<ips.size() && i<ports.size();i++)

Comment: The problem is that it fill at the end my ip list and my ports list with country name, can't understand why, in fact, the problem of the sizes is that

Comment: I looked into the site free-proxy-list.net. The actual proxy list is 300 length. 
There is another table under "Servers" with a list of counties, with single columns.
So, please add more filters, for table specific to: id="proxylisttable"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pull the `ports` from the second column of your table and the `ips` from the first column, but you're ending up with more `ips` than `ports`.

My guess is there's another table in the HTML somewhere, which only has one column (with one row in it).

Other possibilities include that the table is missing a TD in one of its columns.